# Quickselect that runs in O(n) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

So I'm implement a quickselect algorithm that chooses a good pivot each time. What it does is divide the array into groups of 5, sorts each groups and finds the median. It then takes the medians of each group, groups those values up and then finds the median of medians. Here's what I have:

```
private static int pickCleverPivot(int left, int right, int[] A){
    int index = 0;
    int n = right-left;
    if (n <= 5) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        index = n/2;
        return index;
    }
    int numofMedians = (int) Math.ceil(n/5);
    int[] medians = new int[numofMedians];
    int[] groups = new int[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < numofMedians; i++) {
        if (i != numofMedians - 1){
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                groups[j] = A[(i*5)+j];
            }
            medians[i] = findMedian(groups, 5);
        } else {
            int numOfRemainders = n % 5;
            int[] remainder = new int[numOfRemainders];
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfRemainders; j++){
                remainder[j] = A[(i*5)+j];
            }
            medians[i] = findMedian(groups, 5);
        }
    }
    return pickCleverPivot(left, left+(numofMedians), medians);
}

public static int findMedian(int[] A, int n){
    Arrays.sort(A);
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return (A[n/2] + A[n/2 - 1]) / 2;
    }
    return A[n/2];
}

private static int partition(int left, int right, int[] array, int pIndex){
    //move pivot to last index of the array
    swap(array,pIndex,right);


    int p=array[right];
    int l=left;
    int r=right-1;

    while(l<=r){
        while(l<=r && array[l]<=p){
            l++;
        }
        while(l<=r && array[r]>=p){
            r--;
        }
        if (l<r){
            swap(array,l,r);
        }
    }

    swap(array,l,right);

    return l;
}
private static void swap(int[]array, int a, int b){
    int tmp = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = tmp;
}
```

So it works like it's supposed to but now I'm wondering if it's possible to get it to run in linear O(n) time. I'm currently comparing this code to just choosing a random pivot. On smaller arrays this code runs faster but on larger arrays, choosing a random pivot is faster. So is it actually possible to make this run in O(n) time or is that just in theory and if it's not possible for it to run that fast then is this method running as fast as it could.

Comment: Why do you think that just because it's slower, it's not running in O(n) time?

Comment: QuickSelect with a random pivot runs in *expected* O(n) time.  Yours does, too, but you are doing a *lot* of work just to choose a pivot, so the constant factor is greater.